useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/"
I receive an error in the build, with the following messages: useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
✓ Generating static pages (4/4)

Export encountered errors on following paths:
/_not-found
/page:/

This is github code: https://github.com/JuliocesarWpedro/ecommerce
I can fix this error when I put a suspense around the ContextProductsProvider in my layout, which uses useSearchParams(),
But then I start getting a hydration error

In your layout.tsx or layout.jsx file wrap {children} around a react <Suspense> component.
NOTE: You can use <Suspense> in your RootLayout and/or in your Child(other) layout files also.
For eg:
import { Suspense } from "react";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <main>
          <Suspense>{children}</Suspense>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


I'm not sure what you mean by the hydration error, but when you wrap your ContextProductsProvider in a Suspense component, it works.
Ensure to export SimpleFallback from src/components/ContextProductsProvider.tsx
In your src/app/layout.tsx add:
import {
  ContextProductsProvider,
  SimpleFallback,
} from "@/components/ContextProductsProvider";
...

<body className={saira.className} style={{ scrollBehavior: "smooth" }}>
  <Suspense fallback={<SimpleFallback />}>
    <ContextProductsProvider>
      <Header />
      {children}
    </ContextProductsProvider>
  </Suspense>
  <Footer />
</body>
...

It can be more efficient if you move the searchParams state down to a component. Doing so improves the prerendering of the page by the server, which results in a better user experience.

I had already tested this and it works normally for build, but I get the error: Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

When do you get this error? In my case it works when building.
